# bash: split ascii file into n parts; iterate over ONLY those files

Tags: bash, awk, split, parallel-processing, ascii

I have an ASCII file of a few thousand lines, processed one line at a time by a bash script.  Because the processing is embarrassingly parallel, I'd like to split the file into parts of roughly the same size, preserving line breaks, one part per CPU core.  Unfortunately the file suffixes made by `split r/numberOfCores` aren't easily iterated over.

`split --numeric-suffixes=1 r/42 ...` makes files `foo.01`, `foo.02`, ..., `foo.42`, which can be iterated over with `` for i in `seq -w 1 42 ` `` because `-w` adds a leading zero).  But if the 42 changes to something smaller than 10, the files still have the leading zero but the `seq` doesn't, so it fails.  This concern is valid, because nowadays some PCs have fewer than 10 cores, some more than 10.  A ghastly workaround:

```
[[ $numOfCores < 10 ]] && optionForSeq="" || optionForSeq="-w"
```

The naive solution `for f in foo.*` is risky: the wildcard might match files other than the ones that `split` made.

An ugly way to make the suffixes `seq`-friendly, but with the same risk:

```
split -n r/numOfCores infile foo.
for i in `seq 1 $numOfCores`; do
    mv `ls foo.* | head -1` newPrefix.$i
done
for i in `seq 1 $numofCores`; do
    ... newPrefix.$i ...
done
```

Is there a cleaner, robust way of splitting the file into n parts, where 1<=n<=64 isn't known until runtime, and then iterating over those parts?  `split` only into a freshly created directory?

(**Edit:** To clarify "if the 42 changes to something smaller than 10," the same code should work on a PC with 8 cores and on another PC with 42 cores.)

A `seq`-based solution is clunky.  A wildcard-based solution is risky.  Is there an alternative to `split`?  (`csplit` with line numbers would be even clunkier.)  A `gawk` one-liner?

Comment: @Cyrus Replace 9 with a variable, then spend a minute or more trying to get that working again

Comment: `var=9; eval echo {01..$var}` His example contains no real variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a format string with `seq`?

```
$ seq -f '%02g' 1 4
01
02
03
04


$ seq -f '%02g' 1 12
01
02
03
...
09
10
11
12
```

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, yes, it should work fine without the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU bash 4:

Use `printf` to format your numbers:

```
for ((i=1;i<=4;i++)); do printf -v num "%02d" $i; echo "$num"; done
```

Output:

```
01
02
03
04
```

Comment: This is the method I personally prefer. Any time I can dispense with the need to call an external utility such as `seq` and let bash built-ins do the work instead, I do it.

Comment: I'll keep my answer up just to show an alternate approach, but I prefer this one.

Comment: If you wanted to make it more bulletproof you could use the number of digits in `${numOfCores}` (`${numOfCores#}`) to construct the printf mask instead of assuming **2** digits (`%02d`).

Comment: Yes, nice. Thank you. There's a typo: replace `${numOfCores#}` by `${#numOfCores}`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is not a job for GNU Parallel?

```
cat file | parallel --pipe -N1 myscript_that_reads_one_line_from_stdin
```

This way you do not need to have the temporary files at all.

If your script can read more than one line (so it is in practice a [UNIX filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29)), then this should be very close to optimal:

```
parallel --pipepart -k --roundrobin -a file myscript_that_reads_from_stdin
```

It will spawn one job per core and split file into one part per core on the fly. If some lines are harder to process than others (i.e. you can get "stuck" for a while on a single line), then this solution might be better:

```
parallel --pipepart -k -a file myscript_that_reads_from_stdin
```

It will spawn one job per core and split file into 10 part per core on the fly, thus running on average 10 jobs per core in total.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: This is good when `myscript_that_reads_one_line_from_stdin` is slow.  But if that script takes only a few milliseconds, then spawning thousands of those scripts may be slower than making the temporary files and running one process per core.

Answer (score 0):

Get the filenames with `ls` and then use a regex:

```
for n in $(ls foo.* |grep "^foo\.[0-9][0-9]*$") ; do
```

Comment: I suggest to use `for n in foo.[0-9][0-9]; do`.

Comment: Unless there are say four cores, in which case your file names will be `foo.1, foo.2, foo.3, foo.4`, none of which are matched by `foo.[0-9][0-9]`. Wildcard expansion on the command line uses a toy version of regex. Also, `grep` is going to return in less than a millisecond, so why not go with the more powerful approach?

Comment: I understood it this way: the files where created by `split` and "_if the 42 changes to something smaller than 10, the files still have the leading zero_".

Comment: @Cyrus I just looked up the usage info on `split` and it says: `-a, --suffix-length=N   use suffixes of length N (default 2)` so it works exactly as you say.